# Replacing N specific entries in list

Tags: python

I have the following list of strings:

```
['17', ' 5', ' 6', ' 0', ' 0', '', '', '', '', ' 10.11', ' 10.57', ' 18.34', ' 16.41', ' 13.23', ' 11.55', ' 11.56', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 12.77', ' 11.99', ' 21.88', ' 22.46', ' 26.82', ' 25.71', ' 27.43', ' 27.73', ' 29.44', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 28.68', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1.40']
```

This has been parsed from a very messy `.txt` file. Each set of "blank" entries corresponds to one zero, however I need to record these zeroes as 999s (I essentially need to replace every set of 4 consecutive `''` with a `'999'`). What would be the most Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: show the expected result

Comment: If one of answers solved your problem, accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
... 
... 
... def group_blanks_by_n(lst, n=4):
...     result = []
...     for k, g in groupby(lst):
...         if k == '':
...             quo, rem = divmod(sum(1 for _ in g), n)
...             result.extend(['999'] * quo)
...             result.extend([''] * rem)
...         else:
...             result.extend(g)
...     return result
... 
>>> test = ['17', ' 5', ' 6', ' 0', ' 0', '', '', '', '', ' 10.11', ' 10.57', ' 18.34', ' 16.41', ' 13.23', ' 11.55', ' 11.56', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 12.77', ' 11.99', ' 21.88', ' 22.46', ' 26.82', ' 25.71', ' 27.43', ' 27.73', ' 29.44', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 28.68', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1.40']
>>> group_blanks_by_n(test, n=4)
['17', ' 5', ' 6', ' 0', ' 0', '999', ' 10.11', ' 10.57', ' 18.34', ' 16.41', ' 13.23', ' 11.55', ' 11.56', '999', '999', ' 12.77', ' 11.99', ' 21.88', ' 22.46', ' 26.82', ' 25.71', ' 27.43', ' 27.73', ' 29.44', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', ' 28.68', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '', '1.40']
```

---

EDIT:

Added `n` argument to account for different values (doesn't have to default to `4`, only chosen to match the question description).

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot to mention that the best solution in my case would be a function, as I will need to do this for different values of "N" (in this case, it was 4). Cheers :)

Comment: @PythonMania I adjusted the code so that different `n` values can be passed to it. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is by converting the list to string using join(), then replace the spaces with 999 and then convert to list again using split()

```
a = ['17', ' 5', ' 6', ' 0', ' 0', '', '', '', '', ' 10.11', ' 10.57', ' 18.34', ' 16.41', ' 13.23', ' 11.55', ' 11.56', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 12.77', ' 11.99', ' 21.88', ' 22.46', ' 26.82', ' 25.71', ' 27.43', ' 27.73', ' 29.44', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 28.68', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1.40']

b = '*'.join(a).replace(4*'*',' 999 ').replace('*','')
c = b.split()
print c

['17', '5', '6', '0', '0', '999', '10.11', '10.57', '18.34', '16.41', '13.23', '11.55', '11.56', '999', '999', '12.77', '11.99', '21.88', '22.46', '26.82', '25.71', '27.43', '27.73', '29.44', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '28.68', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '1.40']
```

Comment: Sadly does not work if the list starts or ends with 4 trailing `''`.

Comment: well done and very similar to mine which uses a generator expression instead of join to deal with leading/trailing sets of 4 empty strings. 1+

Comment: @alec_djinn It seems like this doesn't return the correct answer. If I understand the question correctly, the end of your `c` variable should be `'999', '', '1.40']` but instead is `, '9991.40']`. Maybe @timgeb missed that before upvoting.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Yep, you are right, I check it up asap.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce It was a wired copy/paste error, the output is correct, but the blank char is gone anyway (because the split) but '999' and '1.40' are separated correctly, not sure if PythonMania wants it in.

Comment: According to the description only groups of 4 are supposed to be replaced. The second last element is a group of one. Also, your solution is deleting the white space around the numbers like ' 5' -> '5'. This is not in the question description at all and seems like another bug.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce then it is not the way to go. I thought that removing witespaces was desirable in this case but you are right, I should have stick to the description of the task.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (aka: [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in Python 3):

#### Code:

```
import itertools as it
new_list = []
N = 4
blanks = ('',) * N
an_iter = it.izip_longest(*[data[i:] for i in range(N)])
for x in an_iter:
    if x == blanks:
        new_list.append('999')
        for i in range(N-1):
            next(an_iter)
    else:
        new_list.append(x[0])
```

#### Results:

```
['17', ' 5', ' 6', ' 0', ' 0', '999', ' 10.11', ' 10.57', ' 18.34', 
 ' 16.41', ' 13.23', ' 11.55', ' 11.56', '999', '999', ' 12.77', ' 11.99',
 ' 21.88', ' 22.46', ' 26.82', ' 25.71', ' 27.43', ' 27.73', ' 29.44',
 '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', ' 28.68', '999', '999', '999', '999',
 '999', '999', '999', '999', '', '1.40']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a little function that does what you need.

```
a = ['17', ' 5', ' 6', ' 0', ' 0', '', '', '', '', ' 10.11', ' 10.57', ' 18.34', ' 16.41', ' 13.23', ' 11.55', ' 11.56', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 12.77', ' 11.99', ' 21.88', ' 22.46', ' 26.82', ' 25.71', ' 27.43', ' 27.73', ' 29.44', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 28.68', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1.40']

def f(list):
    r = []
    c = 0
    for item in list:
        if item == '':
            c += 1
            if c == 4:
                r.append('999')
                c = 0
        else:
            c = 0
            r.append(item)
    return r

print f(a)

['17', ' 5', ' 6', ' 0', ' 0', '999', ' 10.11', ' 10.57', ' 18.34', ' 16.41', ' 13.23', ' 11.55', ' 11.56', '999', '999', ' 12.77', ' 11.99', ' 21.88', ' 22.46', ' 26.82', ' 25.71', ' 27.43', ' 27.73', ' 29.44', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', ' 28.68', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '999', '1.40']
```

Comment: This version completely misses the single empty string second from the end... `'999', '1.40']` should be `'999', '', '1.40']`.

Answer (score 0):

**The most pythonic way** I guess?

```
from itertools import groupby

L = ['17', ' 5', '6', ' 0', ' 0', '', '', '', '', ' 10.11', ' 10.57', ' 18.34', ' 16.41', ' 13.23', ' 11.55', ' 11.56', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 12.77', ' 11.99', ' 21.88', ' 22.46', ' 26.82', ' 25.71', ' 27.43', ' 27.73', ' 29.44', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 28.68', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1.40']

def your_function(L):
    grouped_L = [(k, len(list(g))) for k,g in groupby(L)]
    final_list = [item 
    for x, y in grouped_L 
    for item in repeat(x if y < 4 else '999', y if y < 4 else y // 4)]
    return final_list

print(your_function(L))
```

Use **groupby** and **repeat** from **itertools** which produces a list of tuples like this.

> [(k, len(list(g))) for k,g in groupby(L)]
>
> [('17', 1), (' 5', 1), ('6', 1), (' 0', 2), ('', 4),.. *and so on*]

where the output is a tuple => (item, number_of_it's_consecutive_occurrence)

Then again use **List comprehension**

Note: *(x,y) => (item, number_of_it's_consecutive_occurrence)*

```
final_list = [item 
    for x, y in grouped_L 
    for item in repeat(x if y < 4 else '999', y if y < 4 else y // 4)]
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work properly at all. The question was to replace every set of 4 consecutive '' with a '999'. Your solution replaces any amount of consecutive '' with a single '999'. You missed the empty string second from the end and also destroyed the second zero at `L[4]`.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Was too sleepy back when i posted the answer. Made the correction now with some help from other SO users!

Comment: Your solution does not run because you didn't import `itertools.repeat`. Even when that import is added, your solution is incorrect. There are 33 `''`'s in the last consecutive run of empty strings and `divmod(33, 4) == (8, 1)`. The second last item in `final_list` should therefore be `''` (since it's not a group of 4) but your solution misses that completely. As a side note, the lines inside of your `final_list` list comprehension should be indented.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce No they need not be indented. That is also a correct way of representing list comprehensions.

Comment: You didn't fix your solution even after I pointed out the bugs. Also, your statement about indentation is not backed up by any source. [PEP8 - Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)